# __android_log_print equivalent for printf

Tags: android, c

I am trying to port this logging statement to work, so it will run on linux and android my #define'ing it:

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
```

I have cross-compiled my app to run on both Linux and Android. However, as linux doesn't have the equivalent I have tried to do my own.

```
/** ANDROID */
#if defined(__ANDROID__)
#include <android/log.h>
#define LOG_ERROR ANDROID_LOG_ERROR
#define LOG(PRIORITY, fmt, ...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_UNKNOWN, LOG_TAG, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
/** LINUX */
#elif defined(linux) || defined(__linux) || defined(__linux__)
#define LOG_ERROR LINUX_LOG_ERROR
#define LOG(PRIORITY, fmt, ...) printf(PRIORITY fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

And then using it like this when running under linux

```
LOG(LOG_ERROR, "Testing loggging [ %d ]", test);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it this way. Here is the complete solution.
This would be in a header file

```
typedef enum levels_tag levels_e;
enum levels_tag {
  LOG_UNKNOWN = 0,
  LOG_DEFAULT,
  LOG_VERBOSE,
  LOG_DEBUG,
  LOG_INFO,
  LOG_WARN,
  LOG_ERROR,
  LOG_FATAL,
  LOG_SILENT,
  LOG_LAST
};

/* ANDRIOD IMPLEMENTATION */
#if defined( __ARM_EABI__)
#include <android/log.h>

levels_e levels[LOG_LAST] = {LOG_UNKNOWN,
                             LOG_DEFAULT,
                             LOG_VERBOSE,
                             LOG_DEBUG,
                             LOG_INFO,
                             LOG_WARN,
                             LOG_ERROR,
                             LOG_FATAL,
                             LOG_SILENT};

#define LOG_TAG "MODULE_LOG_SIP"

#define LOGGING(PRIORITY, fmt, ...)  __android_log_print(levels[PRIORITY], LOG_TAG, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)

/* LINUX IMPLEMENTATION */
#elif defined(linux) || defined(__linux) || defined(__linux__)

char *priority_levels[] = {"UNKNOWN",
                           "DEFAULT",
                           "VERBOSE",
                           "DEBUG",
                           "INFO",
                           "WARN",
                           "ERROR",
                           "FATAL",
                           "SILENT",
                           NULL };

#define LOGGING(PRIORITY, fmt, ...)                                     \
    do {                                                                \
        char *priority = priority_levels[PRIORITY];                     \
        printf("%s/%s:%d [%s] " fmt " \n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, priority, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
    } while(0)

#endif

#define LOG(PRIORITY, fmt, ...) LOGGING(PRIORITY, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

And in your source files you would just call the LOG macro like this:

```
LOG(LOG_FATAL, "Failed to create and initialize application instance [ %d ]", errno);
```

Now if you were to compile on linux it would use the printf statement. And if you were to compile on Android it would use the __android_log_print statement. Both would produce the same formatted output.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Why is the `do { ... } while(0)` loop there?

Comment: And why do you first define `LOGGING` and then `LOG`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use family of syslog() functions to make output to system log instead of stdout/stderr (see syslog.h):

```
void openlog(const char *ident, int option, int facility);
void syslog(int priority, const char *format, ...);
void closelog(void);
```

Logs can be viewed in /var/log (file depends on options of syslog, by default in many systems logs are in the file "messages"). Sometimes this way is a better than stdout/stderr, but you have to use openlog/closelog. Unfortunately, syslog's priorities are different comparing to android priorities and thus it doesn't allow simple macro definition with transparent priorities.
Syslog priorities:

```
#define LOG_EMERG   0   /* system is unusable */
#define LOG_ALERT   1   /* action must be taken immediately */
#define LOG_CRIT    2   /* critical conditions */
#define LOG_ERR     3   /* error conditions */
#define LOG_WARNING 4   /* warning conditions */
#define LOG_NOTICE  5   /* normal but significant condition */
#define LOG_INFO    6   /* informational */
#define LOG_DEBUG   7   /* debug-level messages */
```

Priorities of android log:

```
/*
 * Android log priority values, in ascending priority order.
 */
typedef enum android_LogPriority {
    ANDROID_LOG_UNKNOWN = 0,
    ANDROID_LOG_DEFAULT,    /* only for SetMinPriority() */
    ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,
    ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,
    ANDROID_LOG_INFO,
    ANDROID_LOG_WARN,
    ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,
    ANDROID_LOG_FATAL,
    ANDROID_LOG_SILENT,     /* only for SetMinPriority(); must be last */
} android_LogPriority;
```